# I need to create a dictionary from a list of customer views

Tags: python, python-re, text-parsing

I have a string as below

[t] color[+1]##The colors of the watch is very beautiful.##The color is red and very bright.##The color of the previous model, was limited but with this edition it comes with a larger variety of colors. size[-1]##size is limited to medium and large. ##The watch size can be adjusted through the band.

I need to create a dictionary as follows:

watch = {color[+1]:['The color of the watch is very beautiful.', 'The color is red and very bright.', The color of the previous model, was limited but with this edition it comes with a larger variety of colors], size:[-1]:['size is limited to medium and large.', 'The watch size can be adjusted through the band.']}

I am able to split by '##' and I am able to match the pattern (color[+1}) using the regular expression using '\w*[[+|-]{1}\d]' but extracting the 2 strings to create a dictionary is what I struggle with

Answer (score 0):

This code will do the thing.

```
str = "[t] color[+1]##The colors of the watch is very beautiful.##The color is red and very bright.##The color of the previous model, was limited but with this edition it comes with a larger variety of colors. size[-1]##size is limited to medium and large. ##The watch size can be adjusted through the band."
strlist=  str.replace("[t]","").replace(". ","##").split("##")

dictionary = {}
count  = -1
new_key = ""

for i in strlist:
  if not i.strip():
     continue
  if "[" in i and "]" in i:
    count = count + 1
    new_key = i.strip()
    dictionary[new_key] = []
  else:
    dictionary.get(new_key).append(i)

print(dictionary)
```

This is the result.

```
{'color[+1]': ['The colors of the watch is very beautiful.', 'The color is red and very bright.', 'The color of the previous model, was limited but with this edition it comes with a larger variety of colors'], 'size[-1]': ['size is limited to medium and large', 'The watch size can be adjusted through the band.']}
```